# How can I press a button to play a custom sound?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm a complete programming novice and I was wondering how I could have several buttons that play different sounds. I've searched all around and can't figure out this simple task. Thanks!

Comment: You really have two distinct questions here: how to detect individual keystrokes (or maybe you mean GUI buttons?), and how to play sounds. You might have more luck searching for them separately.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple task once you know enough about Objective-C and the Cocoa (Cocoa-Touch on iPhone) frameworks.

Rather than just searching the net for examples you would be better off looking for references on how to program Objective-C and Cocoa.

The steps are:

1. In Xcode, create a controller class that has a method such as this: `- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender;`
2. Create the UI using Interface Builder.
3. Place the buttons you want on this interface and configure their labels.
4. For each of the buttons set a numeric tag (you can do this in interface builder).
5. For each of the buttons set the target to be the controller and the action to be the method you created in step 1. (You do this by ctrl dragging the button onto the controller object in Interface Builder)
6. In the controller class, fill out the method by writing a for loop that checks the tag of of the button (which you can get through the 'sender' object and then [play a sound](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sound/Sound.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000104i) based on the tag.

Depending on your level of experience with Cocoa, this might not make sense right now, but if you read through the references and tutorials for Objective-C and Cocoa each of these steps will become clearer and you'll be able to complete this simple task yourself.

Comment: So then if I wanted it to loop I would say something like

 - (void) sound:(NSSound *)sound didFinishPlaying:(BOOL)playbackSuccessful
{
    if (playbackSuccessful) {
        [i don't know what would go here];
    }
    else {
        [infoTextField setStringValue:@"Playback ended abnormally"];
    }
}

Comment: That's a whole another question.